# jQuery Pull array from JSON response into new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Thank you for the help in advance. I am using a plugin which is expecting a JSON response to be an array not a object. Below is a sample of the JSON response I am getting

```
{
    "instruments": [
        {
            "id": 3316,
            "code": "WES",
            "market_code": "ASX",
            "name": "Wesfarmers Limited",
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "pe_ratio": 16.38,
            "nta": 4.44,
            "eps": 2.55,
            "current_price": 41.78,
            "current_price_updated_at": "2017-10-26T16:10:09.000+11:00",
            "sector_classification_name": "Retail Trade",
            "industry_classification_name": "Food Retail",
            "security_type": "Ordinary Shares",
            "registry_name": "Computershare"
        },
        {
            "id": 2955,
            "code": "RIO",
            "market_code": "ASX",
            "name": "Rio Tinto Limited",
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "pe_ratio": 14.95,
            "nta": 27.77,
            "eps": 4.66,
            "current_price": 69.66,
            "current_price_updated_at": "2017-10-26T16:10:11.000+11:00",
            "sector_classification_name": "Non-Energy Minerals",
            "industry_classification_name": "Other Metals/Minerals",
            "security_type": "Ordinary Shares",
            "registry_name": "Computershare"
        },

    ],
    "links": {}
}
```

The array I need to pull out into its own JSON object is the instruments array.

Now typically I know I would access that data via (if the response variable was called data) data.instruments[0].name as a example which would give me Wesfarmers limited

but if I want that entire array to sit in a new variable, which can then be parsed, how can I get that to happen?

Cheers

Comment: `data.instruments` ?

Comment: hi Jason. thank you for the response i have tried that but the browser/plugin is still seeing it as a object not a array.

Comment: Well.. an array is an object. But `data.instruments` is definitely what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/5t91d7zh/. If that isn't working, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: got it now, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=new Array(data.instruments)
```